# What is the definition of derivative of borel measure $d\mu/dx$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, notation, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

$f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R, x\mapsto f(x)$. $\mu$ is a Borel measure. Is it possible to simplify $$\frac{d}{dx}\int fd\mu$$ to $f\frac{d\mu}{dx}$?

I only learnt the definition of symmetric differentiation of $\mu$ as $$D\mu=\frac{d\mu}{dm}$$ where $m$ is Lebesgue measure.

Could the notation $\frac{d\mu}{dx}$ be properly defined in any ways??

Comment: It is well-defined if $\mu$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure $m$. In this case, $$m(dx) = g(x) \, \mu(dx)$$ for some non-negative measurable function $g$. It is called as the Radon-Nikodym derivative and is often denoted as $g = d\mu/dm$. Then your integral is simply $\int fg \, dm$ and you can apply the standard theory of Lebesgue differentiation.

Comment: @SangchulLee I think you mean $\mu(dx) = g(x) m(dx)$.

Comment: @fourierwho, No doubt I made a silly mistake :( Thank you!

Comment: @SangchulLee I love your answer. The dx in $\mu(dx)$ denotes an infinitesimal interval on $x$, right?

Comment: You are right. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$, then $\mu = \mu_{ac} + \mu_{s}$, where $\mu_{ac}$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.  Let's assume that $\mu(K) < \infty$ whenever $K$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$, though it's not clear to me I need to make this assumption in what follows.  This will enable us to differentiate $\mu$.

Since $\mu_{ac}$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure and $\sigma$-finite, it follows by the Radon-Nikodym Theorem that there is a Borel measureable function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ such that $\int_{-R}^{R} f(x) \, dx < \infty$ whenever $R > 0$ and $\mu_{ac}(A) = \int_{A} f(x) \, dx$ whenever $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is Borel measurable.

The following is proved in textbooks on harmonic analysis:
$$f(x) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{\mu([x - \frac{\epsilon}{2},x + \frac{\epsilon}{2}])}{\epsilon}$$
for each $x \in E$, where the Lebesgue measure of $\mathbb{R} \setminus E$ is zero.

Moreover, if $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is Borel measurable, then 
$$g(x) f(x) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \epsilon^{-1} \int_{x - \frac{\epsilon}{2}}^{x + \frac{\epsilon}{2}} g(y) \mu(dy)$$
for Lebesgue almost every $x$.

**Edit:**  Suppose $\mu$ and $\nu$ are locally finite Borel measures on $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ with $d \geq 1$ (locally finite meaning compact sets get finite measure).  Write $d \mu = f \, d \nu + d \mu_{s}$, where $\mu_{s}$ is singular with respect to $\nu$.  Then there is a $E_{s} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{d}$ such that $\mu_{s}(\mathbb{R}^{d} \setminus E_{s}) = 0$ and 
$$\forall x \in E_{s} \quad \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} \frac{\mu_{s}(B(x,\epsilon))}{\nu(B(x,\epsilon)} = \infty.$$
Similarly, there is a $E_{c} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{d}$ such that $\nu(\mathbb{R}^{d} \setminus E_{c}) = 0$ and
$$\forall x \in E_{c} \quad \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} \frac{\mu_{s}(B(x,\epsilon))}{\nu(B(x,\epsilon)} = 0.$$
Moreover, 
$$\forall x \in E_{s} \quad \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} \frac{\mu(B(x,\epsilon))}{\nu(B(x,\epsilon))} = f(x).$$
The proofs of these statements (at least, the ones I've seen) use covering theorems (Besicovitch's Covering Theorem and a mild version of Vitali's Covering Theorem when $\nu$ is nice).

Comment: Thanks for your great and understandable answer. Could you please give a reference (notes or book) on this topic because I think I need some more formal trainings.

Comment: Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis* is a place to start, especially the chapters on positive Borel measures, complex measures, and differentiation.  (The chapter on differentiation proves you can differentiate measures as in the first equation above.)  I also highly recommend Schlag and Muscalu's *Classical and Multilinear Harmonic Analysis*, where you can learn a bit more about differentiating measures and working with approximate identities.  Also, I edited my response to add some more general facts.

Comment: Finally, for Besicovitch's Covering Theorem, my understanding is Evans and Gariepy's *Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions* is one place to look, but I have yet to crack it open myself.